# MVC4 Routes issues when searching parameters are null or blank

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, global-asax

I am facing the issue with routes and showing exception. it is due to when parameters are null or blank - here when title is blank then issue.

Issue URL : http://{ParentURL}/Admin/Menu/AddEdit/299921b2-3d7b-4e0a-b23e-5838f9b78654/1 - when Title is blank

Working Fine URL : http://{ParentURL}/Admin/Menu/AddEdit/Test/299921b2-3d7b-4e0a-b23e-5838f9b78654/1 -> Here Test Is Title

```
context.MapRoute(
                    "AdminOperation",
                    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{title}/{id}/{pageno}",
                    new { action = "AddEdit", id = UrlParameter.Optional, pageno = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

//controller method

```
public ActionResult AddEdit(string id,  string title, int? pageno)
{
}
```

please help me on it.

Regards

Comment: can you show your controller code?

Comment: added controller method

Comment: The title will not be blank in the "Issue URL", it will be bound to "299921b2-3d7b-4e0a-b23e-5838f9b78654".  Route placeholders are matched simply on the order of the values in the incoming URL.  Are you asking how to handle the error of the missing value or are you asking why the value is missing from the URL?

Comment: I am askineg if Title is blank then , how to manage with mentioned route without creating new one?

Answer (score 1):

If `title` sometimes may be `null`, to my mind, a better approach will be to add one more `route` without it and place it before the `route` you mentioned:

```
context.MapRoute(
           "AdminOperationShort",
           "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{pageno}",
         new { action = "AddEdit", id = UrlParameter.Optional, pageno = UrlParameter.Optional});  


     context.MapRoute(
           "AdminOperation",
           "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{title}/{id}/{pageno}",
           new { action = "AddEdit", id = UrlParameter.Optional, pageno = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional }
                        );
```

Comment: Here using your way it will showing title value of Id in controller method instead of title need to show blank.